# Parallelization of processes. The matrix should be distributed over the processes in a tape manner in alternating columns

Tags: mpi

Help to change the program so that the columns are distributed cyclically through the processes in a ribbon way using MPI.

The whole task: In the integer matrix MxN, reset all the numbers that are composite. The matrix should be distributed over the processes in a tape manner in alternating columns.

```
const int ncolumns = 15; //rows
const int columnlen = 6; //columns
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int** A = NULL;  
    int* Adata = NULL;
    int* sendbufptr = NULL;
    int i, j;
    int** rows;  
    int* columndata;  
    int my_rank, p;
    MPI_Datatype vector_mpi_t;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

    if (my_rank == 0){
        A = (int**)malloc(ncolumns * sizeof(int*));
        Adata = (int*)malloc(ncolumns * columnlen * sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < ncolumns; i++)
            A[i] = &(Adata[i * columnlen]);
        int y=1;
        for (i = 0; i < ncolumns; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < columnlen; j++)
                A[i][j] = ++y;

        printf("Rank 0's 2D array:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < ncolumns; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < columnlen; j++)
                printf("%3ld ", A[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    columndata = (int*)malloc((ncolumns / p) * columnlen * sizeof(int));
    rows = (int**)malloc((ncolumns / p) * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < (ncolumns / p); i++){
        rows[i] = &(columndata[i * columnlen]);
    }

    MPI_Type_vector(columnlen, 1, 1, MPI_INT, &vector_mpi_t);
    MPI_Type_commit(&vector_mpi_t);
    sendbufptr = NULL;
    if (my_rank == 0) sendbufptr = &(A[0][0]);
    MPI_Scatter(sendbufptr, (ncolumns / p), vector_mpi_t, &(rows[0][0]), (ncolumns / p), vector_mpi_t, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("Rank %d's columns: \n", my_rank);
    for (i = 0; i < ncolumns / p; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < columnlen; j++){
            if ((rows[i][j] % 2 == 0 || rows[i][j] % 3 == 0 || rows[i][j] % 4 == 0 || rows[i][j] % 5 == 0 || rows[i][j] % 6 == 0 || rows[i][j] % 7 == 0
                || rows[i][j] % 8 == 0 || rows[i][j] % 9 == 0 || rows[i][j] % 10 == 0) && (rows[i][j] != 2 && rows[i][j] != 3 && rows[i][j] != 5 && rows[i][j] != 7)) {
                rows[i][j] = 0;
            }
            printf("%3ld ", rows[i][j]);}}

    int* recvbufptr = NULL;
    if (my_rank == 0) recvbufptr = &(A[0][0]);
    MPI_Gather(&(rows[0][0]), (ncolumns / p), vector_mpi_t, recvbufptr, (ncolumns / p), vector_mpi_t, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (my_rank == 0){
        printf("\nRank 0's gathered array:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < ncolumns; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < columnlen; j++)
                printf("%3ld ", A[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    MPI_Type_free(&vector_mpi_t);
    MPI_Finalize();
    free(rows);
    free(Adata);
    free(A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a matrix: you have a bunch of arrays. Allocate your matrix contiguously.